# Is this construct a proper use of a private class, and how do I put its instances in that map?

Tags: c++, constructor, private-class

Trying to find a somewhat clean design for sampling billions of dice rolls and while my first ugly solution did work by just creating the generators for the known ranges (dice) it was an ugly mess of multiple typed out by hand copies only changing the range, and switching which to answer the common roll() method with.

```
#include <random>
#include <map>


namespace dnd {

    class Dice {
    private:
        
        class RandomNumberGenerator {
        public:
            RandomNumberGenerator(int from, int to) {
                distr = std::uniform_int_distribution(from, to);
            }

        private:
            std::random_device rand_dev;
            std::mt19937 generator = std::mt19937();
            std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr;
        public:
            int roll() {
                return distr(generator);
            }
        };

        static std::map<int, RandomNumberGenerator> generators;

    public:

        static int dN(int n) {
            if (!generators.contains(n)) {
                generators[n] = RandomNumberGenerator(1, n);
            }
            return generators[n].roll();
        }
    };
```

[image: MSVS error]

Is this construct a proper use of a private class, and how do I put its instances in that map? I suppose something is already wrong with the constructor, despite MSVS not complaining? Not sure if even the basic idea is sound (in C++).

I am trying to move from only creating some generators and create them at program start to create every one I need, as using

````
    public:
        template<typename T>
        static T random(T range_from, T range_to) {
            std::random_device                  rand_dev;
            std::mt19937                        generator(rand_dev());
            std::uniform_int_distribution<T>    distr(range_from, range_to);
            return distr(generator);
        }

        static int d4() {
            static std::random_device                  rand_dev;
            static std::mt19937                        generator(rand_dev());
            static std::uniform_int_distribution<int>    distr(1, 4);
            return distr(generator);
        }
``` ... d20.

is way to slow for the dice not prepared and ugly code wise preparing the expected by hand.
````

Comment: why is there a class in the first place? `Dice` has no (non-static) data members and only 1 static method. The static method can be a free function.

Comment: You should post the full error message rather than a screenshot of the error message. See [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Comment: `generators[n]` requires the values in the map to be default constructible. You dont have to use `[]`, use `generators.find(n)`

Comment: [Why should i not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Side note: Change `RandomNumberGenerator(int from, int to) { distr = std::uniform_int_distribution(from, to); }` to `RandomNumberGenerator(int from, int to) : distr(std::uniform_int_distribution(from, to)) { }` and take advantage of the Member initializer list. This matters because all members are initialized before entering the body of the constructor, so `distr` is default-initialized and then written over in the body of the constructor. This may be doing a bunch of work and then throwing it away.

Comment: @user4581301: Or just to `RandomNumberGenerator(int from, int to) : distr(from, to) { }`, since `distr` is the correct type already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::random_device` can't be copied, therefore instances of your class can't be copied. Bright side, there doesn't seem to be any *reason* to have a `std::random_device` member, since you don't use it, and even if you did (to seed the `mt19937`), you don't need to *keep* it after it's been used. Just change:

```
std::random_device rand_dev;
std::mt19937 generator = std::mt19937();  // Should have been std::mt19937(rand_dev()) to actually seed it at all
```

to:

```
// Seeds it with a temporary instance of random_device
std::mt19937 generator = std::mt19937(std::random_device{}());
```

to both create and initialize the `generator` without preserving a `std::random_device` that never gets used again (it serves no purpose after that point).

You also need to avoid the use of `generators[n]` (which implicitly requires a default constructor for `RandomNumberGenerator`, which it does not have), and make some other small cleanups (e.g. using initialization of `distr` instead of reassigning it after default initialization, and I had to move the definition of `generators` inside `dN`'s definition or you get linker errors for reasons I'm not 100% clear on), but once that is done, it works just fine:

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

namespace dnd {

    class Dice {
    private:
        
        class RandomNumberGenerator {
        public:
            RandomNumberGenerator(int from, int to) : distr(from, to) {}

        private:
            std::mt19937 generator = std::mt19937(std::random_device{}());
            std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr;
        public:
            int roll() {
                return distr(generator);
            }
        };

    public:

        static int dN(int n) {
            static std::map<int, RandomNumberGenerator> generators;
            if (!generators.contains(n)) {
                generators.emplace(n, RandomNumberGenerator(1, n));
            }
            return generators.find(n)->second.roll();
        }
    };
}

int main() {
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      std::cout << dnd::Dice::dN(12) << std::endl;
   }
}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVPLTuMwFF3MLl9hysZRW0RhAaShG5DQbBCaLUKVazvIUmxHfrCp8gV8wmzYzHLW8y_zNVzbaRJK4UqR4-v7OOfY9_df2tTehm_9TOm_x8ncOnZNp9Oz08kMTebVw8-bydPbH--q-eX_H6_HQtHaM45KQxTTcpUNHkma8VZo6wwnEJIpIrltCOWIKYa2WYbAaE2sRbcCvNvoaIx4IY4XcROs_0mhv2LHey833NxxxQ1x2nS5Md9vakGH9GAHc7BQDlVGyxkKf07nqEBMAFycvMGzbbOh8j6yYCBUUUi3uLo6v0DPPZ7rDwc4bpJWa8ZfgO22xXm-_FzKK1FpI9cAaR3BiI13QqsSHKsEb_kt18DF6LrG-UiUnRnuvFEdyx7tHo6237XLxH7Xpz-wjjhBYy92H4VU--26kCQDaQL-2eGLWA262Y9IRIXw0XB4QrVyRCiLVX6I3SiSy6aGl4bVFz3xYgaQvyQ-0mpUtBKKQev5ynJAwk6SzEONlA-iwaMJmkjAursGuFQUhRLwNk6XsJRoAet0KgYqUSyqvUNlGYakKMJgFAVovDjLgzNGcMXq2LXN2jST3Wi-des7)

Comment: The reason you had to move it was because it was just a declaration, not a definition, per the [reference manual about static](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static).

Comment: @TylerKropp: Ah, thanks, forgot that behavior (I rarely use class `static`s). In this case, I think it actually makes more sense as a function static, since it was `private` and never got used anywhere else anyway). May as well tie it more directly to `dN`.

Answer (score 0):

You are copying the object, but your copy constructor is deleted, per the error message:

```
main.cpp:32:31: error: object of type 'mapped_type' (aka 'dnd::Dice::RandomNumberGenerator') cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted
                generators[n] = RandomNumberGenerator(1, n);
                              ^
main.cpp:17:32: note: copy assignment operator of 'RandomNumberGenerator' is implicitly deleted because field 'rand_dev' has a deleted copy assignment operator
            std::random_device rand_dev;
                               ^
...
```

You can find more information about copy constructors here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor

Also look at this answer: [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three/4172724#4172724)

Comment: The take-away: The seed should only be used once, so there's usually no point to storing  a `std::random_device`.